# ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'

Tags: python-3.x, python-imageio

I am trying to read a png file into a python-flask application running in docker and am getting an error that says

> ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode
>   'i'

i have uploaded a file using an HTML file and now i am trying to read it for further processing. i see that scipy.misc.imread is deprecated and i am trying to replace this with imageio.imread

```
if request.method=='POST':
    file = request.files['image']
    if not file: 
        return render_template('index.html', label="No file")
    #img = misc.imread(file)
    img = imageio.imread(file)
```

i get this error :

```
File "./appimclass.py", line 34, in make_prediction

img = imageio.imread(file)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 221, in imread

reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 139, in get_reader

"Could not find a format to read the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode
```

Comment: have also tried >>  img = plt.imread(file) << after >>  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt << but even this gives an error : ValueError: Only know how to handle extensions: ['png'] ... even though my uploaded file is png

Comment: tried running the program locally, that is without the docker environment. Now the error is OSError: cannot identify image file <FileStorage: 'test-1.png' ('image/png')>

Comment: realised that the problem was with the data and not the code. the PNG files were, for some reason, corrupt. could not even open them with GIMP. hence used a fresh set of data files and everything working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the exact same problem recently, and the issue was a single corrupt file. Best is to use something like PIL to check for bad files.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image

dir_path = "/path/"


for filename in listdir(dir_path):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        try:
            img = Image.open(dir_path+"\\"+filename) # open the image file
            img.verify() # verify that it is, in fact an image
        except (IOError, SyntaxError) as e:
            print('Bad file:', filename)
            #os.remove(dir_path+"\\"+filename) (Maybe)
```

Answer (score 9):

Different, but in case helpful. I had an identical error in a different library (skimage), and the solution was to add an extra 'plugin' parameter like so  -

```
image = io.imread(filename,plugin='matplotlib')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, and found that if I closed the file before reading it into imageio the problem went away.

Error was:

```
File "/home/vinny/pvenvs/chess/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py", line 139, in get_reader                                                  "Could not find a format to read the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode  ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'
```

Solution:
Put `file.close()` before `images.append(imageio.imread(filename))`, not after.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option "pilmode":

`imageio.imread(filename,pilmode="RGB")`

It worked for me.

Comment: additional point here: if pilmode="RGB" is used then the image shape changes from (28,28) to (28,28,3). The 3 representing the three channels. Here is the link discussing more on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552402/if-image-has-28-28-3-shape-how-do-i-convert-it-to-28-28-1

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I encountered the same error, and at last, I found it was because the picture was damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I had accidentally saved some images as PDF, so the error occurred. resolved after deleting those incompatible format images.