# read_mrz error : Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'

Tags: python, ocr

The below code is what i am using to read mrz data from a passport, and it works absolutely fine when i run it on my local computer, but when i try to execute it on my server (Windows AWS server) it throws an error.
Can you please help what's this error and how to resolve it.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
from passporteye import read_mrz
import pytesseract

mrz = read_mrz("C:/docs/IMG/PASSPORT/abc.png")
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/qfc_apps/edocs/PY/PASSPORT/passport.py", line 64, in <module>
    passport()
  File "C:/qfc_apps/edocs/PY/PASSPORT/passport.py", line 19, in passport
    mrz = read_mrz("C:/docs/IMG/PASSPORT/abc.png")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\mrz\image.py", line 337, in read_mrz
    mrz = p.result
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\mrz\image.py", line 325, in result
    return self['mrz_final']
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\util\pipeline.py", line 102, in __getitem__
    self._compute(key)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\util\pipeline.py", line 109, in _compute
    self._compute(d)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\util\pipeline.py", line 109, in _compute
    self._compute(d)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\util\pipeline.py", line 109, in _compute
    self._compute(d)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\util\pipeline.py", line 111, in _compute
    results = self.components[cname](*inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\mrz\image.py", line 52, in __call__
    return self._imread(self.file)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\passporteye\mrz\image.py", line 37, in _imread
    img = skimage_io.imread(file, as_gray=self.as_gray, plugin='imageio')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\_io.py", line 61, in imread
    img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\skimage\io\manage_plugins.py", line 210, in call_plugin
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 221, in imread
    reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\functions.py", line 139, in get_reader
    "Could not find a format to read the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode
ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'
```

Comment: PassportEye version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in mode 'i'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379176/valueerror-could-not-find-a-format-to-read-the-specified-file-in-mode-i)

Comment: @SmartManoj, passport eye version is 1.4.1

Comment: After following the above link and adding the plugin in the code, the error changes :-

**image = io.imread(filename,plugin='matplotlib') **


                                                                                                                                                                                      **New error** OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:/qfc_apps/docs/IMG/PASSPORT/abc.png'

Comment: Mention that error too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the solution after hours of research so posting my solution for others who might face a similar solution.

I still couldnt figure out what was the problem with the above code but i managed a way out.

Documentation of passporteye mentions that either we pass the path of the image or a byte stream containing image data. As path was not working for me so i opted for the second method.

Using the below code solves our problem :-

```
image = cv2.imread("path of image")
import PIL.Image as Image
 import io
 pil_im = Image.fromarray(image)
 b = io.BytesIO()
 pil_im.save(b, 'jpeg')
 im_bytes = b.getvalue()

 mrz = read_mrz(im_bytes)
```